# how can I reinstall Heroku on cloud9?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cloud9

I'm taking an online course and it uses cloud9 IDE. After shipping my code to Heroku, I use the command `heroku domains` to view my work but it gives my this message:

> heroku-cli: This CLI is deprecated. Please reinstall from https://cli.heroku.com === francophone-inukshuk-10644 Heroku Domain.

**How could I reinstall it ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue this command:

```
wget -qO- https://cli-assets.heroku.com/install-ubuntu.sh | sh
```

Comment: it's no longer gives me the above message. It gives me === francophone-inukshuk-10644 Heroku Domain
francophone-inukshuk-10644.herokuapp.com but when I open the heroku page I find the page title is Application Error and the content of the page is Application error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.    @Yoni Rabinovitch

Comment: So your heroku CLI is now working. Verify that with "heroku --version". As for the error you are now getting, it sounds like you have some kind of problem with your heroku app. Bu thtat has nothing to do with the question that you asked in this thread, which was how to reinstall the heroku cli on cloud9.